# Troubleshooting Nginx returning random 503 on Wordpress site on Raspberry Pi

Tags: debian, nginx, raspbian

I've started self-hosting a small Wordpress website served by Nginx on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B at home.

Network wise, I had to put my Pi's IP on DMZ (I have a trashy router from my ISP).

It's working fine from my home connection, but accessing my website from some external IPs, it sometimes yields a "HTTP Error 503: The requested service is unavailable". The error is triggered when the client connects and browses a few pages. I've accessed the website from an external wifi connection and worked fine for me. So I have an assumption that this may happen on slower connections.

I've created 2 different access/error.log for in both /var/log/nginx/ and /var/log/nginx/mywebsite/ , which are correctly declared in nginx.conf and my vhost conf file and also have correct ownership and permission.

Neither of these, as well as php5-fpm error/access.log doesn't capture the errors, so I can't measure it.

Maybe some nginx.conf directives are useful to know:

```
worker_processes 4;
worker_connections 65336;
multi_accept on;
keepalive_timeout 15;
client_header_timeout 12;
client_body_timeout 12;
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_buffer_size 1K;
client_max_body_size 64m;
large_client_header_buffer 2 1k;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
```

Can you help me out in getting to the root cause of this? Thanks!

Comment: I'd almost bet it's a problem in php-fpm and probably related to the ressource scarcity of the Rasperry. Can you post the fpm pool config?

Comment: This is everything that's uncommented in /pool.d/www.conf
`[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0666

pm = dynamic

pm.max_children = 9

pm.start_servers = 3

pm.min_spare_servers = 2

pm.max_spare_servers = 2

pm.max_requests = 200

request_terminate_timeout = 300s

chdir = /`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to troubleshoot it finally. Here are the logical steps.

The log files are not capturing anything > have checked and they are working

So if the log files are working, and the HTTP requests are not hitting the machine > Check the router

I've deleted all port forwarding & re-added the port rules > it turns out that the router has primitive buggy software.

After restarting the router with the new port rules, the http requests are finally hitting the machine. Solved!

Comment: Good time to upgrade the router's firmware, if one is available. This can often help with reliability, too.

Comment: Yeah I feel ya, although I need to use the one that the ISP gave me :(